# DAX measure to identify amount for unique column combination

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have data that contains duplications (on purpose) where one project might have multiple categories.

I need to create DAX measure (last column) that would take amount only in case that distCount (distinct count of category per project) column is equal to 1 - distCount is not in dataset and should be calculated as a part of measure.

Last two columns are basically expected result. For example project p2 has only 1 category (c1) in whole dataset but for example project p5 has 3 unique categories (c1,c4,c2). [date] is just for illustration that dataset might be much bigger (in number of column an rows).

```
+-----------+---------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
|   date    | project | category | amount | distCount | measure |
+-----------+---------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
| 4/12/2021 | p2      | c1       | 12.5   |         1 | 12.5    |
| 4/12/2021 | p3      | c1       | 7.5    |         1 | 7.5     |
| 4/12/2021 | p4      | c1       | 72.5   |         2 | 0       |
| 4/12/2021 | p4      | c4       | 72.5   |         2 | 0       |
| 4/12/2021 | p5      | c1       | 57     |         3 | 0       |
| 4/12/2021 | p5      | c4       | 57     |         3 | 0       |
| 4/12/2021 | p5      | c2       | 57     |         3 | 0       |
| 4/11/2021 | p2      | c1       | 15     |         1 | 15      |
| 4/11/2021 | p3      | c1       | 18     |         1 | 18      |
| 4/11/2021 | p4      | c1       | 72.5   |         2 | 0       |
| 4/11/2021 | p4      | c4       | 72.5   |         2 | 0       |
| 4/11/2021 | p5      | c1       | 67     |         3 | 0       |
| 4/11/2021 | p5      | c4       | 67     |         3 | 0       |
| 4/11/2021 | p5      | c2       | 67     |         3 | 0       |
+-----------+---------+----------+--------+-----------+---------+
```

My attempt that is completely wrong (please rather not consider):

```
=IF(
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(data),
FILTER(data,
CONCATENATE(data[category],data[project])=
DISTINCT(CONCATENATE(data[category],data[project]))
))>1,SUM(0),SUM(data[amount]))
```

Comment: IF(E2=1,D2,"") but your measure calculation is not "1 - distcount" as 1 - 12.5 is -11.5 and that is not what you show in your measure column. So not clear.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
measure =
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( data ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( data, data[project], data[category] )
    ) = 1,
    SUM ( data[amount] ),
    0
)
```

This counts the rows in your data table where the `project` and `category` match the current filter context and sums `amount` when that count is singular.

Comment: Thank you Alexis, but I am just not sure where I do mistake: https://prnt.sc/11anfck

Comment: Looks right to me since rows 8-14 are duplicates of rows 1-7 (except for date).

Comment: To get the `distCount` numbers you have, use `data[date]` instead of `data[category]` in the `ALLEXCEPT`. I think your code confused me as to what dimensions you were wanting to be distinct.

Comment: I admit code is bs, sorry for that. However last two columns are basically expected result. for example project p2 has only 1 category (c1) in whole dataset but for example project p5 has 3 unique categories (c1,c4,c2). Dataset might have tens if columns, but I am interested only in these two columns. I will try to reformulate my question.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of using `ALLEXCEPT ( data, data[project], data[date] )`?

Comment: Yes, its closer, but: 1) It sums whole column (cant understand why). -- https://prnt.sc/11ap6uj --  2) How to use that with much larger (and variable) dataset with high number of columns.

Comment: Here you are not defining a measure but a calculated column. If you are defining a calculated column, remove the SUM around `data[amount]`. Why would more columns be problematic?

Comment: Aha, thanks. I did calc column only for visualization. I mean what if date is not in dataset but instead there would be continent and country?

Comment: If you want to consider `project` unique for each country separately, then you'd need to include that column in `ALLEXCEPT`. Otherwise, you wouldn't need to change anything upon adding additional columns.